# How are casino poker dealers paid?

Tags: dealing

Are dealers paid like wait staff where they have a small hourly rate and are expected to make it up in tokes?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized based on this sort of question being closed at other stack sites (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/121806/whats-a-realistic-salary)

Comment: I agree that it's too localized.  As a quick note on your assumptions, I doubt dealers get anywhere close to 2000 hours actually dealing.  They tend to have rotations that include breaks, chip-running, etc.  They also have to deal with tables breaking.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in the structure of their pay. Would it still be too localized if I took out the assumptions?

Comment: I've made edits to the question to make it less "localized" please feel free to close it again if I've failed.